# Unable to find app after install

Tags: android

I am developing an android application, and I have installed it via adb on my android phone.

However it is not being listed on the Applications screen - even though I can see the app in Settings -> Manage my applications. I also tried using the search on my phone - but still no luck. Any ideas ?

Comment: *gets chrystal ball* I think it is in line 34 of your main class!. But kidding aside, it could be you did not declare your activities correctly in your manifest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you didn't set such intent-filter in your AndroidManifest for your "main" activity

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```